# mysql login failing with -h option

Tags: mysql

If I try to login into mysql with -h option, login fails

```
mysql -u keystone_admin -h IP_ADDRESS -p
```

If I use mysql without -h option login is successful

```
mysql -u keystone_admin -p
```

Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Using `-h` logs you into a different server entirely, where your permissions may be different.  Or, are you using the public IP of the same local server? Is MySQL listening for TCP connections? It needs to be if you are to access it via an IP address.

Comment: The server is on our local LAN network. It has loopback and LAN IP address. I am using the LAN IP as -h argument. netstat shows that mysql is listening on 0.0.0.0:3306 tcp connection.

Comment: So what fails? Do you get an access denied error? If so, you probably don't have correct `GRANT`s for the user. You may need to grant access for `keystone_admin@lan_ip` if you currently only have `keystone_admin@localhost` granted.

Comment: Yes I get access denied error. If I query the user table I see 2 entries for keystone_admin user with 127.0.0.1 and % as host values. I presume '%' should handle log-in from remote hosts.

Comment: @yes it should, but are you sure the password is the same? It could be different than the 127.0.0.1 grant.

Comment: Yes it is same. I verified by querying the password fields from % and 127.0.0.1 rows for keystone_admin user from user table.